# npx create-react-app didn't create JSX file

Tags: reactjs

When I created ReactJS project using `npx create-react-app <app name>` command in Terminal, I got JS files by default came in the react project. I am new to ReactJS and I was asked to develop code in JSX files as per requirement. But I am not sure why doesn't `npx create-react-app <app name>` command in Terminal, didn't create even a single JSX file for me.

Reference:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/react.html#install_react_in_empty_project

Can you please tell me should i just rename JS to JSX or why the `npx create-react-app <app name>` command didn't create even a single JSX file in the React project.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please mention cra version? It might be a problem regarding babel.

Comment: @Stella Both works the same. No need to rename files. Could be possibly happened due to CRA version.

Comment: Where can I see CRA version pls?

Comment: @Stella Check for `react-scripts` in package.json

Comment: "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",

Comment: Usually, cra creates the js file, it's up to you to rename the files to your liking. remember React uses jsx, js, and tsx if you're using typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is rarely any difference between `.js` and `.jsx` files as far as **CRA** is concerned. `create-react-app` will create only `.js` files by default. You have to manually change the file extensions of `app.js` and `index.js` to `.jsx` if you want. Since imports don't need to include file-extensions in them, you do not have to change anything else. Both the extensions work exactly the same in react.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize a project, you have only the files which are like boilerplate code. You can start creating files with .jsx extension and work on your react components.

Comment: what about App.js and index.js?

Comment: All files, including App.js, Index.js . It looks more to me like HTML code. I am adding some form in App.js itself. I am not sure why i need to add .jsx extensions further and for what purpose i can add them?

Comment: what happens when you run npm start?

Comment: React home page  runs successfully in localhost

Comment: It works cra doesn't create jsx files, you can use both js and jsx, it's really up to you.

Comment: It is a best practice to use the .jsx extension and if you are using any linting, probably it will throw errors if you use js extension for files having jsx components.